# Watching a video with subtitles

Tags: video, subtitle

Recently, I was looking for a way to watch a video with subtitles. I downloaded HandBrake and now I can merge the files but that way I need to wait around an hour or even more to watch a 40-minute episode, for example. Is there a less time-consuming way?

Answer (score 4):

1. Install VLC player.
2. Open the video in VLC player.
3. Drag and drop the subtitle file in VLC player. Alternatively select the subtitle file from *Menu > Subtitle > Add Subtitle File*.

(VLC is just an example, most of other video players are capable of doing the same.)